# NodeJs: MongoServerError: Transaction numbers are only allowed on a replica set member or mongos

Tags: node.js, mongodb, transactions

> ! When i create a blog by specific user , an error occured related to mongoServer.
> ! here is my createBlogs
> Api code:

```
//Create blog....
const creatBlogs = async(req, res)=>{
    const {title, description, image,user} = req.body
    try {
        let existingUser = await userModel.findById(user)
        console.log(existingUser);
        if(!existingUser){
            return res.status(404).json({message:"Unable to find User by this id"})
        }
        if(!title || !description){
            return res.status(400).json({message:"Missing some fields"})
        }
        const newBlog = new Blog({
            title,
            description,
            image,
            user
        });
        console.log(newBlog);
        const session = await mongoose.startSession();
        session.startTransaction();
        await newBlog.save({session})
        existingUser.blogs.push(newBlog)
        await existingUser.save({session})
        await session.commitTransaction();

        return res.status(201).json({newBlog:newBlog})

    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error occured", error);
    }
}
```

Output: Error occured MongoServerError: Transaction numbers are only allowed on a replica set member or mongos

Comment: Please remove mongoose-web-server tag from this question.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you run your application on standalone mongo server where transactions are not allowed. You should configure replica set or sharded cluster to work with transactions. See [here](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/why-replica-set-is-mandatory-for-transactions-in-mongodb/9533)